# Crashes when using custom IDocHostUIHandler and closing window

Tags: c++, webbrowser-control, c++builder, mshtml, twebbrowser

I use custom `IDocHostUIHandler` attached to a TWebBrowser (in design mode). It works. However, when the program exits (or the window using it closes) it crashes. I suppose something is not deleted/destroyed properly. I assume that the custom IDocHostUIHandler is still in use after it is destroyed so I should somehow destroy web browser first (or detach the custom .

So my question is - how do I properly destroy custom `IDocHostUIHandler` so that when existing the program doesn't crash or detach the custom `IDocHostUIHandler`?

If I remove the `diCustDoc->SetUIHandler(piDocUIHandler)` in constructor it works without any crashes so the problem is definitely caused by attaching custom `IDocHostUIHandler`.

Setting the `diCustDoc->SetUIHandler(NULL);` before the above `Release()` (in destructor) crashes too.

My custom `IDocHostUIHandler` (replaces popup menu and customizes the `GetHostInfo`).

```
    class TDocUIHandler : public ::IDocHostUIHandler
        {
        private:
            ULONG        RefCount;
            TPopupMenu* pPopupMenu;

        public:
            //TDocUIHandler()                     : RefCount(0)                         {}
            TDocUIHandler(TPopupMenu* fPopupMenu) : RefCount(0), pPopupMenu(fPopupMenu) {}

            // IUnknown method
            HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
                {
                if (!ppv) return E_POINTER;

                if        (IsEqualIID(riid, IID_IUnknown))          *ppv = static_cast<IUnknown*>(this);
                else if (IsEqualIID(riid, ::IID_IDocHostUIHandler)) *ppv = static_cast< ::IDocHostUIHandler*>(this);
                else                                                *ppv = NULL;

                if (*ppv)
                    {
                    AddRef();                                                // Used the first time so increase the RefCount
                    return S_OK;
                    }

                return E_NOINTERFACE;
                }

            ULONG __stdcall AddRef()
                {
                return (ULONG) InterlockedIncrement((long*)&RefCount);
                }

            ULONG __stdcall Release()
                {
                ULONG res = (ULONG) InterlockedDecrement((long*)&RefCount);
                if (res == 0) delete this;

                return res;
                }

            // Returning S_OK tells the web browser that it need not display its
            // own context menu, presumably because the application hosting it has
            // displayed its own menu to replace it.
            // Since our host does not display any, no context menu is shown.

            STDMETHOD(ShowContextMenu)(         /* [in] */ DWORD dwID,
                                                /* [in] */ POINT __RPC_FAR *ppt,
                                                /* [in] */ IUnknown __RPC_FAR *pcmdtReserved,
                                                /* [in] */ IDispatch __RPC_FAR *pdispReserved)
                {
                // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa753264(v%3Dvs.85)
                switch (dwID)
                    {
                    default:                    break;
                    case CONTEXT_MENU_DEFAULT:
                    case CONTEXT_MENU_IMAGE:    pPopupMenu->Popup(ppt->x, ppt->y);
                                                break;
                    }

                return S_OK;
                }

            STDMETHOD(GetHostInfo)(                /* [out][in] */ DOCHOSTUIINFO __RPC_FAR *pInfo)
                {
                if (pInfo == NULL) return E_POINTER;

                pInfo->cbSize = sizeof(DOCHOSTUIINFO);
                pInfo->pchHostCss       = NULL;
                pInfo->pchHostNS        = NULL;
                pInfo->dwDoubleClick    = ::DOCHOSTUIDBLCLK_DEFAULT;  // default action

                pInfo->dwFlags          = 0
                                        | ::DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DIV_BLOCKDEFAULT
                                        | ::DOCHOSTUIFLAG_ENABLE_FORMS_AUTOCOMPLETE
                                        | ::DOCHOSTUIFLAG_THEME
                                        | ::DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DPI_AWARE
                                        ;

                return S_OK;
                }

            STDMETHOD(ShowUI)(                  /* [in] */ DWORD dwID,
                                                /* [in] */ IOleInPlaceActiveObject __RPC_FAR *pActiveObject,
                                                /* [in] */ IOleCommandTarget __RPC_FAR *pCommandTarget,
                                                /* [in] */ IOleInPlaceFrame __RPC_FAR *pFrame,
                                                /* [in] */ IOleInPlaceUIWindow __RPC_FAR *pDoc)
                {
                return E_NOTIMPL;
                }

            STDMETHOD(HideUI)(void)
                {
                return E_NOTIMPL;
                }

            STDMETHOD(UpdateUI)(void)
                {
                return E_NOTIMPL;
                }

            STDMETHOD(EnableModeless)(          /* [in] */ BOOL fEnable)
                {
                return E_NOTIMPL;
                }

            STDMETHOD(OnDocWindowActivate)(        /* [in] */ BOOL fActivate)
                {
                return E_NOTIMPL;
                }

            STDMETHOD(OnFrameWindowActivate)(   /* [in] */ BOOL fActivate)
                {
                return E_NOTIMPL;
                }

            STDMETHOD(ResizeBorder)(            /* [in] */ LPCRECT prcBorder,
                                                /* [in] */ IOleInPlaceUIWindow __RPC_FAR *pUIWindow,
                                                /* [in] */ BOOL fRameWindow)
                {
                return E_NOTIMPL;
                }

            STDMETHOD(TranslateAccelerator)(    /* [in] */ LPMSG lpMsg,
                                                /* [in] */ const GUID __RPC_FAR *pguidCmdGroup,
                                                /* [in] */ DWORD nCmdID)
                {
                return E_NOTIMPL;
                }

            STDMETHOD(GetOptionKeyPath)(        /* [out] */ LPOLESTR __RPC_FAR *pchKey,
                                                /* [in] */ DWORD dw)
                {
                return E_NOTIMPL;
                }

            STDMETHOD(GetDropTarget)(           /* [in] */ IDropTarget __RPC_FAR *pDropTarget,
                                                /* [out] */ IDropTarget __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppDropTarget)
                {
                return E_NOTIMPL;
                }

            STDMETHOD(GetExternal)(                /* [out] */ IDispatch __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppDispatch)
                {
                return E_NOTIMPL;
                }

            STDMETHOD(TranslateUrl)(            /* [in] */ DWORD dwTranslate,
                                                /* [in] */ OLECHAR __RPC_FAR *pchURLIn,
                                                /* [out] */ OLECHAR __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppchURLOut)
                {
                return E_NOTIMPL;
                }

            STDMETHOD(FilterDataObject)(        /* [in] */ IDataObject __RPC_FAR *pDO,
                                                /* [out] */ IDataObject __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppDORet)
                {
                return E_NOTIMPL;
                }
        };
```

Code to attach the above handler (in constructor):

```
TDocUIHandler* piDocUIHandler;

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
{
piDocUIHandler = new TDocUIHandler(PopupMenu1);

WB->Navigate("about:blank");
while (WB->Busy) { Application->ProcessMessages(); Sleep(50); }

DelphiInterface<IHTMLDocument2> diDoc = WB->Document;
if (diDoc)
    {
    diDoc->designMode = "on";

    DelphiInterface< ::ICustomDoc> diCustDoc;
    if (SUCCEEDED(WB->Document->QueryInterface( ::IID_ICustomDoc,(void**)&diCustDoc)) && diCustDoc)
        {
        if (SUCCEEDED(diCustDoc->SetUIHandler(piDocUIHandler)))
        {
        //MSGBOX("Success!");
        }
    else
        {
        // FAIL
        }
    }
}
```

In form destructor:

```
__fastcall TForm1::~TForm1()
    {
    piDocUIHandler->Release();
    }
```

The code found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa753260(v%3Dvs.85)

Saves the default IDocHostUIHandler. Not sure if I need that, but the guide there tells something about avoiding memory leaks to perform `IObjectWithSite::SetSite(NULL)` - not sure if that applies to this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not performing reference counting on your `TDocUIHandler` object correctly.

The object's refcount is initially 0.  Your Form maintains an active reference to the object (FYI, it should be in a class data member, not in a global variable), but does not increment its refcount accordingly.  Thus, when `SetUIHandler()` is called, it saves its own reference to the object and calls `AddRef()` on it, so the object's refcount is 1, even though it actually has 2 active references.

When your Form destructor is called, it `Release()`'s the object, decrementing the refcount to 0, so the object `delete`'s itself, even though the WebBrowser still has an active reference to it.  When the WebBrowser is cleaning up, it tries to `Release()` its reference to the object and crashes since it doesn't know the object was already destroyed.

Try this:

```cpp
IDocHostUIHandler* piDocUIHandler;

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
{
    piDocUIHandler = new TDocUIHandler(PopupMenu1);
    piDocUIHandler->AddRef(); // <-- ADD THIS!!

    ...
}

__fastcall TForm1::~TForm1()
{
    piDocUIHandler->Release();
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
DelphiInterface<IDocHostUIHandler> piDocUIHandler; // <-- use DelphiInterface instead!

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
{
    piDocUIHandler = new TDocUIHandler(PopupMenu1); // <-- calls AddRef() for you!
    ...
}

__fastcall TForm1::~TForm1()
{
    piDocUIHandler.Release(); // <-- note '.' not '->' !

    or:

    piDocUIHandler = NULL; // <-- calls Release() for you!
}
```

Comment: Your explanation makes sense of course, but why if I breakpoint the implemented `Release()` method it never reaches 0 for the return value `res`? In another project it also crashes in CodeGuard but I think that is due to conflict with EmbeddedWB which I am removing from that project (as in a blank new project which doesn't use EmbeddedWB, CodeGuard remains silent for the same code). Still in both projects, `res` never reaches 0 for the `ULONG res` return value, the last one is always 1 just before exit.

Comment: @Coder12345 for an auto-created `TForm`, such as the `MainForm`, its destructor is not called until *after* `WinMain()` exits, when the `TApplication` object is destroyed. Are you accounting for that?